# The excel file is created by using DocumentFormat.OpenXML but need to repairing when opeing in Excel

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am new for DocumentFormat program.I searched the web and found the example to export dataset to excel using OpenXML. Following the code, the excel file is generated. However when the file is open, there is an issue that the Excel indicated that "a problem with some content in report. Do you want us to try to recover as much as we can?.." when the user clicked yes, the data is fine. I searched the website and look like the string column type  by using InlineString is ok. Am I wrong? I have no idea which code cause the problem. Would someone can tell me? Thanks in advance.

There is the code I found in the web:

```
namespace ExcelObject
{
public class ExcelStream
{
    SpreadsheetDocument document = null;   

    public MemoryStream GetExcelStream(DataSet dataset)
    {
        DataSet ds = dataset;
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            //Create workbook in memory
            document = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(ms, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook);

            //Add workbook
            var workbookpart = document.AddWorkbookPart();
            workbookpart.Workbook = new Workbook();

            //add worksheet to wrokbook
            var worksheet = workbookpart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
            worksheet.Worksheet = new Worksheet(new SheetData());


            var sheets = document.WorkbookPart.Workbook.AppendChild(new Sheets());
            //Add a new worksheet and associte it with the workbook.
            var mainSheet = new Sheet()
            {
                Id = document.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheet),
                SheetId = 1,
                Name = "TestReport"
            };

            sheets.Append(mainSheet);

            uint rowIndex = 0;

            //Get sheet data
            var sheetData = worksheet.Worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>();
            var row = new Row { RowIndex = ++rowIndex };
            AddColumnHeaderRow(ds, row, sheetData);
            AddDataRows(ds, rowIndex, sheetData);
            workbookpart.Workbook.Save();
            document.Close();
            return ms;


        }
    }

    private static void AddColumnHeaderRow(DataSet ds, Row row, SheetData sheetData)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            var cell = new Cell { DataType = CellValues.InlineString, StyleIndex = 1 };
            var inlineCell = new InlineString();
            var cellText = new Text { Text = ds.Tables[0].Columns[i].ColumnName };
            inlineCell.AppendChild<Text>(cellText);
            cell.AppendChild<InlineString>(inlineCell);
            row.AppendChild<Cell>(cell);

        }
        sheetData.AppendChild(row);

    }

    private static void AddDataRows(DataSet ds, uint rowIndex, SheetData sheetData)
    {
        for (var r = 0; r < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; r++)
        {
            var row = new Row { RowIndex = ++rowIndex };
            for (var c = 0; c < ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count; c++)
            {

                var cell = new Cell { DataType = CellValues.InlineString };
                var istring = new InlineString();
                var t = new Text
                {
                    Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[r][c].ToString()

                };
                istring.AppendChild<Text>(t);
                cell.AppendChild<InlineString>(istring);
                row.AppendChild(cell);
            }
            //append each data row to sheet data
            sheetData.AppendChild<Row>(row);
        }
    }
}
}
```

There is my code to generate the table and get the result:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Dim dt As New DataTable("Test")     
    dt.Columns.Add("Code", GetType(String))
    dt.Columns.Add("Price", GetType(String))

    Dim dr As DataRow = dt.NewRow()
    dr("Code") = "ABC"
    dr("Price") = "12"

    dt.Rows.Add(dr)

    Dim dr1 As DataRow = dt.NewRow()
    dr1("Code") = "DEF"
    dr1("Price") = "1"

    dt.Rows.Add(dr1)
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    ds.Tables.Add(dt)

    Dim t As ExcelStreamObject.ExcelStream = New ExcelStreamObject.ExcelStream
    Dim ms As MemoryStream = t.GetExcelStream(ds)

    Response.Clear()
    Response.ClearContent()
    Response.ClearHeaders()
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=TestReport.xlsx")
    Response.BinaryWrite(ms.ToArray())
    Response.Flush()
    Response.Close()
    Response.End()

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what is wrong of my code. The AddColumnHeaderRow having Style that I didn't have. So I changed the "var cell = new Cell { DataType = CellValues.InlineString, StyleIndex = 1 };" to be "var cell = new Cell { DataType = CellValues.InlineString };" The error message didn't show when opening the file.